# Executeable Tkinter plus selenium

Tags: python, selenium, executable, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

WEll , i am getting hard to make this works, i have tried Cx_freeze

but its showing this:

[image: With Cx_freeze]

This is the Setup:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need fine tuning.
build_exe_options = {"packages": ["os"], "excludes": ["tkinter","schedule","selenium"]}

# GUI applications require a different base on Windows (the default is for a
# console application).
base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(  name = "Yad2AutoAd",
        version = "0.1",
        description = "Auto Jumper for Yad2 Advertises",
        options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
        executables = [Executable("Yad2Ads.py", base=base)])
```

and with pyinstaller its showing this:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 64, in start
  File "subprocess.py", line 859, in __init__
  File "subprocess.py", line 1114, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] \u200f\u200fלמערכת אין אפשרות לאתר את הקובץ שצוי
ן

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Yad2Adv.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __ini
t__
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 71, in start
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executabl
e needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chrome
driver/home

Failed to execute script Yad2Adv
Exception ignored in: <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.chrom
e.service.Service object at 0x0000000002C3D668>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 163, in __del_
_
  File "site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 135, in stop
AttributeError: 'Service' object has no attribute 'process'
```

Well its kind a the same error i think , what should i do i tried to insert the selenium folder into the same folder with the exe file.
I think this post is pretty detailed, and sorry if looks like a long script.
just want to make sure you guys understand this problem.
Thanks in advance!
P.S
The Code for Initialise webdriver:

```
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

and the PhantomJs.exe is in the same folder as the project.

Comment: Could you share the code for initialising chromedriver as well??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur - Added at the bottom of the question, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Well after Saurabh Gaur told me if i was initialising the web driver, have re-thinking about it again and search for it , well you have to make executeable-path
for you webdriver for example:

```
phantomdriver = r"C:\Users\Bar\PycharmProjects\Yad2FinalFix\phantomjs.exe"
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=phantomdriver)
```

this solved my problem, thank you Saurabh Gaur you have saved me many times!